# How to completely delete an object through python?

Tags: python, objects

How to completely delete an object **without** using:

```
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

bpy.ops methods are too slow for my script, so far I am able to delete an object with a simple:

```
del obj
```

But Blender does not reset/delete names of the deleted objects with this method, so I end up with Cube.344, Cube.599, etc..

Also, deleted objects are not linked to the scene.

Comment: Removing 1000 suzannes takes `0.011783123016357422` seconds (on my thinkpad). I think that's really fast. I guess you are using the operator in a loop, right? Also consider this [comment](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/python-how-to-completely-remove-an-object/27235#comment41086_27234)

Comment: That is correct, operator in a loop for individual objects.

Comment: That's the reason why it takes so long... I'd suggest select all objects, then call the operator one time, this way it's safe and fast as well.

Comment: Updated my answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27235/3710

Comment: That is an acceptable option as long as I don't create new object data.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I also added how to cleanup the data blocks... Can you elaborate?

Comment: There would be more memory usage if I copy object data without linking. Also, the object_name.XXX would not be incremental for the remaining objects at the end of the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the [remove](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.BlendDataObjects.html#bpy.types.BlendDataObjects.remove) function.

```
import bpy
objs = bpy.data.objects
objs.remove(objs["Cube"], do_unlink=True)
```

The code above deletes an object named "Cube." The first parameter of the `remove` function is the object to remove, the second is a boolean about first unlinking the object (you want it set to True.)

Comment: Possibly this answer could be to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/python-how-to-completely-remove-an-object?rq=1

Comment: wow, it does work well