# Removing a group with no users

Tags: scene, groups, data-blocks

I have a problem in deleting a group named "Group" in this file.

[image]

How I made this file

1. I made the "Group" in my first scene.
2. I made another scene and deleted the first scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this right using [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75344/how-to-completely-delete-an-object-through-python).

```
grs = bpy.data.groups
grs.remove(grs["Group"], True)
```